# Cloud Container Builder authentication token issue

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-container-builder

I tried running the following code on [Cloud Container Builder](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs) using the `npm` builder:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'some-bucket-name';

test(`can access GCP`, async (t) => {
  await storage
    .createBucket(bucketName)
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Bucket ${bucketName} created.`);
      t.pass();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      t.fail();
    });
});
```

When I did this, I got a `404 page not found` error. How do I fix this?

In case it helps, I also tried using the [Data Loss Prevention API](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs) and it gave me an error saying `Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Could not refresh access token.`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to [a bug](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/google-auto-auth/pull/34) in a dependency of [google-auto-auth](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/google-auto-auth) that was fixed as of version `0.9.2`.

Unfortunately, the client libraries (such as `@google-cloud/storage`) have not yet been updated to use this version of `google-auto-auth`. Until they are updated, you can work around this by overriding transitive dependencies. If you're using `yarn` (instead of `npm`), add the following section to your `package.json` file:

```
"resolutions": {
  "google-auto-auth": "^0.9.2"
}
```